# OAuth Post Authentication Re-Login

Tags: python, flask, oauth, flask-oauthlib

Once the user has gone to the provider and granted access to my web application, I recieve some tokens which I store in Postgres under that user. Once the user logs out, and then at some future time wants to sign back in and clicks "Login in with X" how do I just log them in not forward them to the "Authorize this Application" page again?

Python 3.5

Flask

Flask-OAuth

Flask-Login

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Search for your OAuth [authorize_handler](https://flask-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#flask_oauthlib.provider.OAuth2Provider.authorize_handler). This function may return rendered HTML page to show user or boolean to confirm if user authorized the application. You can check if your database already has bearer token for given client and user and just return `True` if it exists. This is the modified [example](https://flask-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html#authorize-handler) from Flask-OAuthlib documentation:

```
@app.route('/oauth/authorize', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@require_login
@oauth.authorize_handler
def authorize(*args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        client_id = kwargs.get('client_id')
        client = Client.query.filter_by(client_id=client_id).first()
        # Getting user object
        user = current_user()
        # Getting tokens for this user and client
        tokens = BearerToken.query.filter_by(client_id=client_id, user_id=user.id)
        for token in tokens:
            # Checking if requested scopes are within given token scopes
            if set(token.scopes) >= set(kwargs['scopes']):
                return True
        kwargs['client'] = client
        return render_template('oauthorize.html', **kwargs)

    confirm = request.form.get('confirm', 'no')
    return confirm == 'yes'
```